# FFMpeg Workflow for editing on growing file

Tags: command-line, audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I have a HP Z600 server with NVDIA Quadro 4000. I am into live streaming and currently working for a leading Sports Broadcaster in India.

I am new to FFMpeg world and we have a new requirement to Decode a HLS stream as input and have MXF XDCAM 50 for output.

Workflow:
I am planning to set a FFMpeg workflow where I will receive input as HLS (m3u8) "Live Stream" (1280*720), Capture it in MXF XDCAM 50 (1920*1080) on ffmpeg. The capture will be stored on a Network storage. This MXF file will be imported on Adobe Premier Pro for editing VOD packages on growing file.
We have a 1gig network for this operation.

Below is the FFmpeg command I am using.

ffmpeg -re -i "http://input.m3u8?fifo_size=50000" -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv422p -vcodec mpeg2video -non_linear_quant 1 -flags +ildct+ilme -top 1 -dc 10 -intra_vlc 1 -qmax 6 -lmin "1*QP2LAMBDA"  -rc_max_vbv_use 1 -rc_min_vbv_use 1 -b:v 50000k -minrate 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 36408333 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -bf 2 -f mxf Y:\Test\MYTEST.mxf

Observation:
The output of this command when imported on Adobe Premier Pro has Audio Video outsync of 2-3 frames. Also after completing almost 90 mins of capture the AV outsync increases in secs or even minutes.

Questions:

1. Is there something more required in the command line to resolve the outsync issue?
2. Is there any flag for ffmpeg to run error free for longer durations for 8-10 hours?
3. Is there any flag to be added to ignore errors in the live stream? Like we have -overrun_nonfatal for UDP TS.
4. How many such captures I can start simultaneously on a single server with the configuration that I have?

Regards,
Sagar Shirke

Comment: Does `ffmpeg -i "http://input.m3u8?fifo_size=50000" -c copy cap.mp4` produce a file where A and V is in sync?

Comment: Thank you for replying. As per the workflow we need XDCam MXF to edit on growing file.

Comment: I'm asking you to check for debugging purposes.

Comment: Sure. I will share the observations of this test.

Comment: By the time can you please answer to the questions listed in my message?

Comment: Hello Mulvya, The output of ffmpeg -i "http://input.m3u8?fifo_size=50000" -c copy cap.mp4 is out of sync. Around 1-2 seconds.

Comment: What about `ffmpeg -i "input.m3u8?fifo_size=50000" -c:v copy -af aresample=async=1 cap.mp4`?

Comment: I am not able to playback the output of this command ffmpeg -i "input.m3u8?fifo_size=50000" -c:v copy -af aresample=async=1 cap.mp4. Does not give me any error but it just doesnt play on VLC.

Comment: What's the output of `ffprobe cap.mp4`?

Comment: It says, " [mov, mp4, m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000006b9b40] moov atom not found cap.mp4: Invalid dada found when processing input"

Comment: That means ffmpeg was interrupted when you ran the 2nd command. Run it again and show its console output.

Comment: I have retried the 1nd command and checked the output. It is still 2secs out of sync.

Comment: Did you receive the URL?